# How to scroll list view to the current item?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a list view. If i click on a cell, that specific cell need to move to the center with a small scrolling animation. With my code, the clicked cell will comes to the center without any animation.

Is it possible to add animation for that ?

Am putting my code below :

```
    ListView {
        id: source_list
        width: 1080
        height: 480
        spacing: 50
        model: mediaSongsModel
        delegate: mediaSongsDelegate
        focus: true
        interactive: true
        clip: true
        highlightMoveDuration: 50
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
        boundsBehavior:Flickable.StopAtBounds
        preferredHighlightBegin: 260/scaleFactor
        preferredHighlightEnd: 260/scaleFactor
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    }                

    Component {
        id: mediaSongsDelegate
        Item {
            id: wrapper
            width: 1080
            height: 200

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    source_list.currentIndex = index
                    source_list.positionViewAtIndex(index,ListView.Center)    
                }
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code you had provided is not work. Your items delegate isn't visible. What is `scaleFactor`? Please update the code with *working* example if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the current item should always be in the center or within a specific are of the view, then you can use the `preferredHighlightBegin` and `preferredHightlightEnd` properties to define that area.

The value of `highlightRangeMode` controls if and if yes, how strictly this applies. E.g. if the first item is the current item and the value is `StriclyEnforeRange` then the item will be within the specified area even if that means scrolling further up than a normal "scroll to top" would.

Something like that should work

```
ListView {
    preferredHighlightBegin: height / 2 - 100 // 100 being item height / 2
    preferredHighlightEnd: height / 2 + 100 // 100 being item height / 2
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
}
```

Comment: but this works for me. but there is no scroll up/scroll down animation happening by this.

Comment: Strange, when I do that the new current item moves into the preferred range and the list moves accordingly.

Comment: Actually issue was in source_list.positionViewAtIndex(index,ListView.Center)  ;                          when i removed that it worked. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's why I had only the necessary bits in my answer

Answer (score 4):

I've solved my issue by removing the following line of code:

```
source_list.positionViewAtIndex(index,ListView.Center);
```

The animation correctly worked.